# Android: Resetting the splash screen

Tags: android, splash-screen

On my Android App, I have set up a splash screen. The splash screen opens when the app is opened and lasts for two seconds before it redirects to a login screen.

The issue I am having is that the splash screen displays once, and then re-directs to the login screen. BUT when I click on the app again it goes straight to the login screen ignoring the splash screen... Is there a reason for this? Does it automatically open on your last screen? Because then if I hit the back button when it opens on the login screen it DOES go back to the splash screen but then doesn't redirect to the login screen after 2 seconds.

Someone has said: "Set clearTaskOnLaunch via the Android Manifest of your project to true. This will clear the task/stack history whenever the activity is launched." -- But I don't know where to put it in the Anndoird Manifest.. and I'm not even sure this is the solution to my problem as I effectively want the whole app to be started again when then icon is clicked -- not resumed on the last page.

Help?!

THanks

Comment: Post your splash screen code.

Comment: I followed this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/user/ponzicoder#p/c/87FA0FB3611241B5/3/C6J_RWOKmYw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you **want** the splash screen to show when pressing back from the login activity? Because any user would **hate** that. Do your users a favor and call `finish()` after starting the login activity from the splash screen. However, if you actually care for your users a little bit you would remove the splash screen altogether (unless you have some data to load, or something that **actually takes two seconds to complete, and can't be postponed**).

Now, on to your main problem. Yes, the Android OS does keep your activity stack in memory for a while, but only if you use the <kbd>HOME</kbd> button to effectively minimize the application. If you press the back button, the activity is terminated. When there are no more activities, the process is terminated (using the back button). It's not recommended to override this behavior, so I won't post any pointers on that (although others already have).

Comment: I essentially just want the splash screen to display once at the beginning every time the app is opened.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` in the Android Manifest file where your 'Splash Activity' is defined with the `<activity/>` tag.

There is a clear explanation of the behaviour [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/da024bcaf4e1960f?pli=1).

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this working. It's now coming up and STAYING on the splash screen. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean it is 'staying' on the splash screen?

Comment: In the emulator, when I click the 'Home' button and then relaunch the app, it stays on the splash screen... However, if I press the back button to get back to the home screen it will display the splash screen and then go to the login screen correctly.

Comment: Posted a link that might help. This is specific to your code. Remember that the activities in the previous stack will still go through the activity lifecycle - finish() will be called.

Answer (score 1):

Hitting 'back' doesn't terminate your application. Hence it goes back to the last opened screen. If you terminate your application, the splash will re-appear (as you stated).

[This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) is an interesting read for you.

Comment: In which case, what would be the best solution to this? Would the clearTaskOnLaunch="true" achieve this?

Comment: android:clearTaskOnLaunch is actually a better idea, as mentionned by Che.

Comment: -1, I don't see how overriding `onPause()` would help. Also, overriding `onPause()` is very recommended (?)

Comment: I think he meant overriding onPause() to catch the home button behaviour. @Bart by the way did you mean hitting 'home' instead of 'back'?

Comment: Felix: you are absolutely correct, I edited my mistake out.
Che: I didn't mention 'hitting home' ..

Comment: In that case doesn't the default behaviour of hitting 'back' call finish() on the current activity?